# Prestashop: Combinations not showing

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i've got a problem with combinations in my prestashop 1.6.0.9. Combinations just not showing in product page for example here - http://b-bservis.cz.webar.cz/home/8-jolly-fix.html there should be 3 combinations with different prices. I dont know what happend, but color picker and another (also default) combinations doesn't working too.

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try activating the default theme, and navigate to the product page to see if the combinations show up. If they do show up, then you have a problem with your theme.

Answer (score 0):

According to source file of his website, he's already using default-bootstrap theme.

Also according to the source file, product attributes are present, they just don't show up on product page.

```
<div id="attributes">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
            <label class="attribute_label">Balení&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="attribute_list">
                <ul id="color_to_pick_list" class="clearfix">
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="http://b-bservis.cz.webar.cz/zakladni-natery-penetracni/8-jolly-fix.html" id="color_25" name="" class="color_pick selected" title=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://b-bservis.cz.webar.cz/zakladni-natery-penetracni/8-jolly-fix.html" id="color_26" name="" class="color_pick" title="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://b-bservis.cz.webar.cz/zakladni-natery-penetracni/8-jolly-fix.html" id="color_27" name="" class="color_pick" title="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" class="color_pick_hidden" name="group_4" value="25" />
            </div>
            <!-- end attribute_list -->
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I had same problem with an earlier version of PrestaShop, after digging for hours I finally solved the issue.

You can [check my post on PS forum](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/384123-single-attribute-texture-displayed-instead-of-all-variants-product-list/) and see if it helps.